# apresentar mensagem dados salvo com sucesso para usuario!

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap-3

Gostaria que apresentase uma mensagemna tela assim que usuario salvar os dados, estou querendo um alert desses que está no link abaixo, segue o codigo:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CODIGO DA PAGINA:

```
<?php


 session_start();

$codUsuario = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];
$ieqbairro = $_POST['ieqbairro'];
$pastor = $_POST['pastor'];
$lider = $_POST['lider'];
$celulaAtivas = $_POST['celulasativas'];
$participantes = $_POST['participantescelulas'];
$quantidadereunioes = $_POST['quantidadereunioes'];
$quantidaensamensal = $_POST['quantidaensamensal'];
$diaensaio = $_POST['diaensaio'];
$horaensaio = $_POST['horaensaio'];
$totalmembrosdepartamento = $_POST['totalmembrosdepartamento'];
$vocal = $_POST['vocal'];
$mulhercontralto = $_POST['mulhercontralto'];
$mezzosoprano = $_POST['mezzosoprano'];
$soprano = $_POST['soprano'];
$homensbaixo = $_POST['homensbaixo'];
$baritono = $_POST['baritono'];
$tenor = $_POST['tenor'];
$guitarra = $_POST['guitarrista'];
$baterista = $_POST['bateristas'];
$tecladista = $_POST['tecladistas'];
$violao = $_POST['violao'];
$baixo = $_POST['baixistas'];
$meialua = $_POST['meialua'];
$cajon = $_POST['cajon'];
$outros = $_POST['outros'];
$ministeriodecarreira = $_POST['ministeriocarreira'];
$descrinomemstcarreira = $_POST['nomeministeriocarreira'];
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ficha_Cadastral_Musica (CodUsuario,ieqbairro, pastor, lider, celulaAtivas, participantescelulas, quantidadereunioes, quantidaensamensal,diaensaio, horaensaio, totalmenbrosminis, vocalquant, mulhercontralto, mulhermezzosoprano, mulhersoprano, homensbaixo, homensbaritono, homenstenor, guitarraqtd, bateristaqtd, tecladistaqtd, violaoqtd, baixoqtd, meialuaqtd, cajonqtd, outros, ministeriodecarreira, descrinomemstcarreira) VALUES ('$codUsuario','$ieqbairro', '$pastor', '$lider', '$celulaAtivas', '$participantes', '$quantidadereunioes', '$quantidaensamensal', '$diaensaio', '$horaensaio', '$totalmembrosdepartamento','$vocal', '$mulhercontralto', '$mezzosoprano','$soprano', '$homensbaixo', '$baritono', '$tenor', '$guitarra', '$baterista', '$tecladista', '$violao', '$baixo', '$meialua', '$cajon', '$outros', '$ministeriodecarreira', '$descrinomemstcarreira')") or die('Erro ao inserir ao banco de dados'); 

if($query){

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Dados Salvo com Sucesso!</div></div>';



    }


mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

---

Bom aparece só a escrita na tela, mais não aparece o alert verde igual está no bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o que acontece quando você executa o código?

Comment: Nota que vc está fechando a div 2x no `echo`: `</div></div>`.

Comment: Coloque esse no seu if: `else { echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">Falha ao Salvar os Dados!</div>';}`

Comment: estou fazendo meu codigo na pagina php assim, mais da erro
if($query){
   '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">'

     ' <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'
      '<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'
    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">Sucesso ao Salvar os Dados!</div>';
 

 
    }

Comment: ai da esse erro aqui 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<script src="https://maxcdn.b' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\commeq\salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php on line 42

Answer (score 0):

Verifique  se suas importações do bootstrap, foram importadas corretamente.
Teste o link Online:

O css: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

O JS e Jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

E verifique se essa div irá reconhecer.

Tente modifcar sua div para: `echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Dados Salvo com Sucesso!</div>"`

Se não funcionar você trabalhar com sessões e verificar se o seu "IF" está correto.

Outra solução seria você mesmo criar os Style dentro da DIV. E ir personalizando do seu jeito. Não precisa necessariamente pegar a Class do Bootstrap - Faz uma sua que seja parecida. 
Ex: `<div style="border: 1px solid green; color: white; backgroud-color: green; border-radius:5px;">exemplo</div>`

Answer (score -1):

Favor verificar se os scripts do Bootstrap estão sendo carregados na página.
Se o Bootstrap não for carregado na página não adianta usar as classes e tags do bootstrap, nenhum CSS vai ser aplicado.

Para utilizar o bootstrap é necessário incluir um import dos arquivos bootstrap.min.css e bootstrap.min.js (Verificar [documentação do bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/)).